# Duplicate Symbol Linker Error With Firebase CocoaPods

Tags: ios, firebase

I had been developing a an iPad iOS app using the simulator until recently when I got my hands on an iPad with iOS 8.

I had been adding a couple of frameworks and going on just fine and the project has always built and run fine for the simulator (and it still does).

However, building for the device fails with an error about duplicate symbols (220 of them!) for the Firebase (2.5.0) Target in the Pods Project. I tried all the basics of cleaning the project, making sure Obj-C related flags were in place, but nothing.

I decided to see if somehow during work some configuration got broken so I tested on a fresh project, with Firebase as the only Pod and with nothing else done but setting up the workspace with 'pod install' and I get the exact same error.

All the duplicate symbols seem to be regarding the same file (libFirebaseStatic.a) and very many o-files.

This is the error, but I have chopped off a large middle part of the error for obvious reasons:

```
duplicate symbol _llvm.cmdline in:
    /Users/RCR/Documents/DEV/IOS/Business/BLBusiness/Pods/Firebase/libFirebaseStatic.a(FPendingPut.o)
    /Users/RCR/Documents/DEV/IOS/Business/BLBusiness/Pods/Firebase/libFirebaseStatic.a(FBase64Utilities.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.embedded.module in:
    /Users/RCR/Documents/DEV/IOS/Business/BLBusiness/Pods/Firebase/libFirebaseStatic.a(FPendingPut.o)
    /Users/RCR/Documents/DEV/IOS/Business/BLBusiness/Pods/Firebase/libFirebaseStatic.a(FBase64Utilities.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.cmdline in:
    /Users/RCR/Documents/DEV/IOS/Business/BLBusiness/Pods/Firebase/libFirebaseStatic.a(FPendingPut.o)
    /Users/RCR/Documents/DEV/IOS/Business/BLBusiness/Pods/Firebase/libFirebaseStatic.a(FLevelDBStorageEngine.o)
.
.
.
duplicate symbol _llvm.embedded.module in:
    /Users/RCR/Documents/DEV/IOS/Business/BLBusiness/Pods/Firebase/libFirebaseStatic.a(FPendingPut.o)
    /Users/RCR/Documents/DEV/IOS/Business/BLBusiness/Pods/Firebase/libFirebaseStatic.a(FTransformedEnumerator.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.cmdline in:
    /Users/RCR/Documents/DEV/IOS/Business/BLBusiness/Pods/Firebase/libFirebaseStatic.a(FPendingPut.o)
    /Users/RCR/Documents/DEV/IOS/Business/BLBusiness/Pods/Firebase/libFirebaseStatic.a(FClock.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.embedded.module in:
    /Users/RCR/Documents/DEV/IOS/Business/BLBusiness/Pods/Firebase/libFirebaseStatic.a(FPendingPut.o)
    /Users/RCR/Documents/DEV/IOS/Business/BLBusiness/Pods/Firebase/libFirebaseStatic.a(FClock.o)
ld: 220 duplicate symbols for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't ask me why or how, but updating Xcode (to 7.2) solved this issue. I did not pay attention to what was my previous version before updating but it had to be 7.1 or 7.1.1.

In any case, the issue is gone. I assume that the Firebase library had compiling requirements only met by the latest update to Xcode.